# Java ArrayList Middle

Tags: java, collections, arraylist

How to find the middle of an ArrayList ?

Comment: Have you meant middle or median?

Comment: it's between the index and the ring finger

Comment: ArrayList.imTooLazyToWriteUpAQuestionProperly().

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have `N` items, the middle item is usually defined as item at index `N/2` (0-based).

```
10 items
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
          |
          5

13 items
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2
            |
            6
```

Generally, if you need to find the middle of items between index `low` (inclusive) and `high` (exclusive), it's mathematically `int mid = (low + high) / 2`. But due to arithmetic overflow in limited-precision integer, the proper formula is `int mid = (low + high) >>> 1;`

#### See also

- Google Research Blog post by Josh Bloch

  - [Extra, Extra - Read All About It: Nearly All Binary Searches and Mergesorts are Broken](http://googleresearch.blogspot.com/2006/06/extra-extra-read-all-about-it-nearly.html)

Comment: Thanks for the link to Bloch's article. Very useful info.

Answer (score 6):

```
ArrayList.size()/2
```

Answer (score 3):

If the size of ArrayList is **even** in number, then use
     **(ArrayList.size()/2)+1** or    **(ArrayList.size()/2)** as the middle.
If the size of ArrayList is **odd** in number, then use     **(ArrayList.size()+1)/2** as the middle.